# Meaning of "I never got to say that."

Tags: have-got

> 'Cause I was an asshole
> And I hate that
> And I never got to say that
> So let me come over
> And be with you one more time

In this lyrics,
What is the meaning of "I never got to say that"?
I know gotta=got to=have to.
So, does it mean "I shouldn't say that (but I didn't or I did.)"?
Or "(I had to say that but) I didn't say that."

Comment: This may be more appropriate for [ell.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Never got to" means "never had the opportunity to" or "never got around to".  So they are basically regretting that they never managed to say they were sorry.

I did something bad. I didn't want to. I wanted to tell you that, but I never did.